How to customize tokenEndpoint in oauth2Login in webflux?
i'm configuring spring security in my webflux app and would like to customize a custom accessTokenResponseClient in the tokenEndpoint. In non-reactive app, i can do it by providing a tokenEndpointConfigurer like this:
httpSecurity.oauth2Login(oAuth2LoginConfigurer ->
            oAuth2LoginConfigurer.tokenEndpoint(tokenEndpointConfig -> tokenEndpointConfig.accessTokenResponseClient(customTokenResponseClient))
        );

However in reactive app i have to use ServerHttpSecurity and the oauth2Login in ServerHttpSecurity does not have a simular function to customize the tokenEndpoint, something like:
serverHttpSecurity.oauth2Login(oAuth2LoginSpec -> oAuth2LoginSpec.tokenEndpoint???);

Can anyone give me a suggesstion to to this?
I did search some documentations but no success
